# Display notice box when input wrong password to unlock content which is encrypted by Cryptojs

Tags: encryption, cryptojs

I use Cryptojs to encrypt my text, and I use below code to decrypt:

```
 <div id="decrypt-box">
 <div class="decrypt-form" id="decryption" data-href="U2FsdGVkX1+Fg5XynZFlZHmhvMhAw9l7jlKt2WEpYYWEkOy7L360rZ7xd19TvoXp">
<div> password to unlock: asd</div>
 <form action="#" id="decrypt-form" method="post">
<input autofocus="" id="decrypt-password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" />

        <input class="decrypt-button" type="submit" value="Unlock" />
    </form>
<div id="decrypt-alert">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id='decrypt-content'></div>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script>
document.getElementById('decrypt-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
var c=document.getElementById('decryption');
    var encryptedMsg=c.getAttribute('data-href'),
        passphrase = document.getElementById('decrypt-password').value,
        decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedMsg, passphrase);
        decrypted = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);                                    

        document.getElementById('decrypt-content').innerHTML = decrypted;    

});
</script>
```

**My question is:**

How do I do to display notice box if I input wrong password.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to use an HMAC to determine if the password was correct or not.

Comment: #Luke Joshua Park, Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: Well, AES just transforms a block of 128-bits to another block of 128-bits using a key.  Any key will work with AES, you'll just get a *different* block of 128-bits than you were expecting if the key is incorrect.  So you need to HMAC the original data and keep the result with your ciphertext.  Then once you finish decrypting, you can HMAC again and see if they match.  If they do, it's the correct password.

Comment: #Luke Joshua Park, Can you give me an example? sorry for my bad skill.

Comment: You can research this yourself, there is plenty of information available online.

Comment: #Luke Joshua Park, thanks